# PostgreSQL clever use of ST_Within

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

maybe my question can seem stupid, but I'd like to ask if somebody can tell me how can I improve this query:

```
UPDATE twitter
   SET poi=poi.type_name FROM poi
 WHERE ST_Within (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x_coords,y_coords),4326),
 ST_SetSRID(ST_Buffer(poi.wkb_geometry, 0.0005),4326));
```

I have 2 tables with points: "`twitter`" and "`poi`", I need to create a **buffer of 50m around "`poi`"** and find all points of "`twitter`" which are within this buffer and then copy "`type_name`" attribute of "`poi`" to "`twitter`" point.
The problem is that the query lasts too long and seems it'll never finish, from time to time I try to check if some attributues were copied, but "`twitter.poi`" column remains always empty.

I tried to limit the query by adding in **WHERE "`username`"** to check if the query is right and it works.

```
UPDATE twitter
       SET poi=poi.type_name FROM poi
     WHERE uname='some_username' AND ST_Within (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x_coords,y_coords),4326),
     ST_SetSRID(ST_Buffer(poi.wkb_geometry, 0.0005),4326));
```

The only one thing that I can't understand is how to improve the query for entire "`twitter`" table.

Comment: You didn't think to mention that you are working with the [PostGIS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgis/info) extension? And its version? And whether you have [an appropriate index](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html)?

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry, I'm a newbie in this field and didn't think this could be useful info. I have 1.5.3 version of Postgis and to be honest I didn't create any index. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: `x_coords,y_coords` have no table qualification and you didn't provide table definitions.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide a table definition, but you seem to have two columns for the coordinates in table `twitter` : `x_coords` and `y_coords`. Either replace those with a `geometry` column and create a simple GiST index or create a functional GiST index like:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_twitter_point_4326
ON twitter  USING gist (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x_coords,y_coords), 4326));
```

And another one on `poi`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_poi_wkb_geometry_4326
ON poi USING gist (ST_SetSRID(p.wkb_geometry, 4326));
```

This should be used to speed up `ST_Within()`:

> This function call will automatically include a bounding box
>   comparison that will make use of any indexes that are available on the geometries.

The function [ST_distance()](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ST_Distance.html) might serve you better:

```
UPDATE twitter t
SET    poi = p.type_name
FROM   poi p
WHERE  ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(t.x_coords, t.y_coords), 4326)
                  ,ST_SetSRID(p.wkb_geometry, 4326)) < 0.0005
AND    t.poi IS DISTINCT FROM p.type_name;
```

This is assuming there can *at most one* `poi` in the vicinity of a `twitter` entry. Else you should use a subquery that picks the *closest* `poi` for each `twitter`.

The additional `WHERE` clause `t.poi IS DISTINCT FROM p.type_name` avoid empty updates.

Not using PostGis myself, so untested.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! I have created indexes for "poi" table and I'm still creating it for "twitter" table (4 hours passed and it's still working, the table has almost 268.000 records). I have also geometry column in "twitter" table, so I used it for create indexes. I'll let you know if using indexes will speed up the query. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm sorry, but using created indexes didn't help me. After some hours of waiting for the query to be executed and without seeing any updates, I decided to write some code in C# where I used my second query (with username in "WHERE" clause) in loop for every username in "Twitter" table. If you have any other suggestions or an idea why the query is too slow, you are welcome! Thanks again for trying to help!